# Does not Retrieve all data of mysql in android through volley

Tags: android

hi i want to retrieve all data from mysql and display on listview  in android through volley and php  but i receive only one record in response object 
and display only one record in listview i don't  know where is where is error.
My Android Code is

```
JsonArrayRequest  jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
           hide();


                ////////get json data
                for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){

                    try {
                      Log.d("the ","response  "+response);
                      JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(i);
                       item item=new item();
                       item.setTitlwimage(obj.getString("Title_Image"));
                        item.setTitle(obj.getString("Vedio_Title"));
                        item.setDescription(obj.getString("Description"));
                        item.setCate(obj.getInt("S_category_Id"));
                       // item.setTime(obj.getDouble("Datetime"));

                    list.add(item);

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Error"," and "+String.valueOf(response));
                }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        Singleton.getinstance().addtorequest(jsonArrayRequest);


        //System.out.println("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"+t.getText());
    }
```

and JSON formate is

```
[{"Vedio_Id":"16","Vedio_Title":"A touching commercial that rubs the deepest p","Title_Image":"192.168.43.2\/Library\/pimages\/download (5).jpg","Description":"2011 commercial by MOE (Ministry of Education","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UIun5xGK86g","Datetime":"2017-08-09 16:58:23","S_category_Id":"1"}][{"Vedio_Id":"16","Vedio_Title":"A touching commercial that rubs the deepest p","Title_Image":"192.168.43.2\/Library\/pimages\/download (5).jpg","Description":"2011 commercial by MOE (Ministry of Education","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UIun5xGK86g","Datetime":"2017-08-09 16:58:23","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"17","Vedio_Title":"Suli Breaks - Why I Hate School But Love Educ","Title_Image":"images (13).jpeg","Description":"Get tickets to my LIVE SHOW at THE ROCK TOWER","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=y_ZmM7zPLyI","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:06:39","S_category_Id":"1"}][{"Vedio_Id":"16","Vedio_Title":"A touching commercial that rubs the deepest p","Title_Image":"192.168.43.2\/Library\/pimages\/download (5).jpg","Description":"2011 commercial by MOE (Ministry of Education","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UIun5xGK86g","Datetime":"2017-08-09 16:58:23","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"17","Vedio_Title":"Suli Breaks - Why I Hate School But Love Educ","Title_Image":"images (13).jpeg","Description":"Get tickets to my LIVE SHOW at THE ROCK TOWER","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=y_ZmM7zPLyI","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:06:39","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"18","Vedio_Title":"Funny children are just the best at entertain","Title_Image":"download (6).jpg","Description":"Children are awesome! These kids and toddlers","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=1-drtOAgH_o","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:12:26","S_category_Id":"1"}][{"Vedio_Id":"16","Vedio_Title":"A touching commercial that rubs the deepest p","Title_Image":"192.168.43.2\/Library\/pimages\/download (5).jpg","Description":"2011 commercial by MOE (Ministry of Education","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UIun5xGK86g","Datetime":"2017-08-09 16:58:23","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"17","Vedio_Title":"Suli Breaks - Why I Hate School But Love Educ","Title_Image":"images (13).jpeg","Description":"Get tickets to my LIVE SHOW at THE ROCK TOWER","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=y_ZmM7zPLyI","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:06:39","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"18","Vedio_Title":"Funny children are just the best at entertain","Title_Image":"download (6).jpg","Description":"Children are awesome! These kids and toddlers","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=1-drtOAgH_o","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:12:26","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"19","Vedio_Title":"TRY NOT TO LAUGH or GRIN Funny Fails Vines Co","Title_Image":"images (17).jpeg","Description":"This year is just flying by! This month's bes","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=no0u9MeK1XY","Datetime":"2017-07-19 11:11:17","S_category_Id":"5"}][{"Vedio_Id":"16","Vedio_Title":"A touching commercial that rubs the deepest p","Title_Image":"192.168.43.2\/Library\/pimages\/download (5).jpg","Description":"2011 commercial by MOE (Ministry of Education","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UIun5xGK86g","Datetime":"2017-08-09 16:58:23","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"17","Vedio_Title":"Suli Breaks - Why I Hate School But Love Educ","Title_Image":"images (13).jpeg","Description":"Get tickets to my LIVE SHOW at THE ROCK TOWER","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=y_ZmM7zPLyI","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:06:39","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"18","Vedio_Title":"Funny children are just the best at entertain","Title_Image":"download (6).jpg","Description":"Children are awesome! These kids and toddlers","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=1-drtOAgH_o","Datetime":"2017-07-17 16:12:26","S_category_Id":"1"},{"Vedio_Id":"19","Vedio_Title":"TRY NOT TO LAUGH or GRIN Funny Fails Vines Co","Title_Image":"images (17).jpeg","Description":"This year is just flying by! This month's bes","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=no0u9MeK1XY","Datetime":"2017-07-19 11:11:17","S_category_Id":"5"},{"Vedio_Id":"20","Vedio_Title":"Funny videos 2016 - funny videos 2016 funny v","Title_Image":"images (15).jpeg","Description":"funniest video ever you will die of laughter,","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=CZB9vLWyHtQ","Datetime":"2017-07-19 11:11:17","S_category_Id":"5"}]
```

And php code is

```
<?php 

include('Connection.php');
$sql = "select * from vedio";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $response=array();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $response[]=$row;       
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

}
else{

echo mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

and in response object retrieve  only

```
[{"Description":"2011 commercial by MOE (Ministry of `Education","Title_Image":"http:\/\/192.168.43.2\/Library\/pimages\/asd.jpg","Link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=UIun5xGK86g","Vedio_Title":"A touching commercial that rubs the deepest p","S_category_Id":"1","Vedio_Id":"16","Datetime":"2017-08-09 17:38:36"}]`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your array everytime the next row is fetched. try this:

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    array_push(  $response,$row);                       
}
     echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: AFAIK using empty index in array `$response[]=...` will not overwrite it, it will add element to it

Comment: @Yazan just place the json_encode($response) out of while loop.

Comment: @deejay yes, that's in my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

just put `echo json_encode($response);` out of the while loop
because you print the response on first loop, that's what the server sends back to the request you send.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $response[]=$row;       
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

encode and send the response when the loop finish all iterations.